# Is there a way to inject configuration settings(IConfiguration) in a view or cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read the **Appsettings.json** file in a view or cshtml directly. Is this possible? In a class i can just pass into my constructor as `IConfiguration` and then use it to get sections of my config like `_configuration.GetSection("Application:AppDomain").Value` so i am trying to do the same to the views or cshtml directly. Is there a way?

Comment: Views are for displaying, not processing. Why do you want to do any kind of processing in the view instead of the controller?

Comment: I was trying to inject my API link to an ajax script. I will look for a better way to do it and pass it using a controller but for now i have to use this shortcut

Comment: The better way is to use a view as a view and a controller as a controller. No you don't have to use this non-shortcut at all. You can't even have a view without a controller. You're already passing data through either a model or ViewBag. You have to put extra effort, to really go out of your way to break this pattern.

Comment: What you ask is trivial using MVC: add `IConfiguration` in the constructor, use it wherever you need it and pass the settings you want in the model or through ViewBag. It's no different than passing any other kind of data to the view. The view will never know where the data came from and can easily be tested with dummy data

Comment: I am thinking of using TempData as Viewbags wont survive if the page refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that by injecting the `IConfiguration` on your `View`. It will look like this:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<h1>@Configuration.GetSection("Application:AppDomain").Value</h1>
```

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should

Comment: @DavidG Well it depends on the implementation and what you are trying to achieve by using the configuration settings on the `View`. Maybe hide/show a section based on the configuration, assign the relative path for your scripts etc.

Comment: Even then I would inject a proper class with properties, not directly IConfiguration

Comment: @RahulSharma no it doesn't. No these aren't valid uses.  This is a very, very, very bad idea. Views display. They don't process. They don't need any kind of configuration. *Controllers* process. If a view needs to display anything conditionally it will take the information from the data passed to it by the controller. That's what allows views to be developed independently from the rest of the system. Injecting `IConfiguration` in the controller constructor is trivial. So is passing any data through the model or a ViewBag

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay I understand your point sir. Are there any drawbacks that you can outline using IConfiguration on the View? You are right that the Controller should process the configuration elements. I just wanted to understand the implications and drawbacks of using configuration on the View

Comment: Breaking the separation between view and controller, making the code more complex. Duplicating code between the *multiple* views supported by a single controller or even action. Adding a hard-coded dependency on a service that has nothing to do with the view or controller, thus making testing harder. Making the view susceptible to config schema changes almost a dozen levels and a team away. Making it impossible to change how the data is generated without having to modify the view itself - that's what the MVC pattern was built to avoid.